# How to upgrade app signature from V1 to V2?

Tags: android, ionic3, signature

I have a ionic-3 app signed with V1 signature (jar signed) and its published at Google store. Now, starting August 2021, new apps will be required to target API level 30 (Android 11).

So, I changed the API level to 30 and signed with V1 signature, but Google did not accepted the APK.

What is the standard way to upgrade the app signature from V1 to V2?

Answer (score 4):

You can't "upgrade" an app signature, instead simply resign the app using the correct signing tool.

This means do **no longer use** `jarsigner` for signing the apk file(s)!

Instead use `apksigner` (`apksigner.bat`/`apksigner.sh` on Windows/Linux) for signing your app. apksigner is part of the Android SDK build-tools. Recent versions of apksigner (e.g. from build-tools version 31.x/30.x/29.x always create an V1+v2 signature by default (I assume the older versions, also do v1/v2 signatures, but I am not sure).

Comment: Can I use the same .keystore  file to sign the v2 signature?

Comment: @Nirmalya You can use the same keystore, the underlaying cryptography is still the same.

Answer (score 0):

If you do all your signing within android studio, watch the options when you are making a release build. It should give you the options for v1 and v2 sigining, and you can select v2. That signed apk should be acceptable to Google play.